# HttpClient Get 401

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to call a Tableau endpoint to get the list of project.
It is in 2 steps:

- Call the signIn endpoint to get a token that allow to call others endpoint
- Call the list projects endpoint with my signed In token

By using insomnia, this is working like a charm, but in csharp code, the first step is working well, but the second always returning me a 401 error.
[image: insomnia call]

> [Tableau list projects documentation](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_projects.htm#query_projects)

```cs
public async Task<string> ListProjectAsync()
{
    var signIn = await SignInAsync(); // Working
    var endPoint = $"https://myTableauSite.com/api/3.17/sites/{signIn.SiteId}/projects";

    var acceptedCodes = new List<HttpStatusCode>();
    acceptedCodes.Add(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Tableau-Auth", signIn.Token);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(endPoint); // 401

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseString;
}
```

**Edit**: The problem was from the JWT generated token that had a missing permission, my bad

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I could find between your code's request and insomnia is that you forgot to set the content-type

```
public async Task<string> ListProjectAsync()
{
    var signIn = await SignInAsync(); // Working
    var endPoint = $"https://myTableauSite.com/api/3.17/sites/{signIn.SiteId}/projects";

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Tableau-Auth", signIn.Token);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(endPoint); // Should be working
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it silent crash at the line that add the Content-Type